# In C++, how to initialize an non-copyable static member variable in class?

Tags: c++, static, initialization

I'm mimicking the code here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#idp343130416. I want to rewrite the code in a class, using static members to implement the functionality.

However, I found I can't initialize non-copyable static member variable in class. For example, in the class, the following code doesn't work:

```
class ProgramOptions{
private:
static po::options_description config("Generic options");
}
// Possible reason: visual studio treat it as function declaration.

class ProgramOptions{
private:
static po::options_description config = po::options_description config("Generic options");
}
// Possible reason: in C++, only the int type can be done this way. 
// For other types, static variable can't be evaluated where it's declared.

class ProgramOptions{
private:
static po::options_description config;
static void InitializeSaticMemberVariables()
    {
        generic = po::options_description("Generic options");
    }
}
// warning C4512: assignment operator cannot be generated.
// Possible reason: options_description is not copyable and the operator = has been intentionally disabled.
```

I searched many pages still failed to solve it. What should I do?

I don't want to manage the members in the non-static way, since it's weird to have many instances of program options.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when typing the question. The second way is     static po::options_description config = po::options_description("Generic options");  The third way is config = po::options_description("Generic options");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first alternative should work if your compiler supports C++11 and brace-initialization:

```
static po::options_description config{"Generic options"};
```

Note that you still need to actually *define* the variable as well.

---

The second variant could possibly be used, but you initialize the variable in the *definition*:

```
class ProgramOptions{
private:
    static po::options_description config;
    ...
};

...

po::options_description ProgramOptions::config = po::options_description config("Generic options");
```

However, this breaks the non-copyable point, as it will use the copy-constructor.

Comment: I tried your first proposal and got `error C2864: 'ca::ProgramOptions::generic' : a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const integral type`. I am using visual studio 2013, and I think it should support C++11 and brace-initialization. Some other things went wrong. Actually, one of the static variable is config, and the other is generic. They are used the same way, so I mistook them when typing.

Comment: It seems your second approach works: I tried ` po::options_description ProgramOptions::generic = po::options_description("Generic options");
` and visual studio intellisense accepted it. However as in my third approach when I wrote the = assignment in a static member function: the compiler gave errors. Is there any difference for these two type use of =?

Comment: It seems `po::options_description ProgramOptions::hidden{ "Hidden options" };` also works outside the class scope.

Comment: @JohnSmith When you have an assignment in a variable definition, it's an *initialization* and it invokes the copy-constructor (unless the compiler does [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)). Otherwise it's a normal assignment.

Comment: `po::options_description ProgramOptions::generic("Generic options");` outside the class scope works too. Is it some C++ rule here so that I can't use options_description like general class for example the string class?

Comment: @JohnSmith When you use the parentheses inside the class (the first alternative in your question) it seems to be some variant of [the most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: Thank you very much. The declaration and definition of static member variable is kind of wired. I't more like a function than a variable.